# ASUS Socket 1150 Z87 Motherboards - Differences?

Tags: motherboard

I understand that the H81 / H87 (models?) can't be overclocked and the Z87 can.  But what is the difference between:

```
ASUS Z87-A
ASUS Z87-C
ASUS Z87-K
ASUS Z87-PLUS
ASUS Z87M-PLUS
ASUS Z87-PRO
ASUS Z87-DELUXE
```

Is there a general theme?  I've tried looking on the [ASUS site](http://www.asus.com/uk/Motherboards/) and Googling but it's a hard thing to search for.

Comment: There isn't. Its simply a brand specific model separation, and will be different between brands, and even generation.

Answer (score 0):

Okay on further research it looks like there's no easy pattern / theme here - each type has a multitude of varying properties compared to the others.

From what I've read in the specs, this is roughly the order I would place them in (starting with the most features).  There are many more differences, these are just the main ones in my opinion.

```
DELUXE     WiFi / Bluetooth / 6 x USB-3 / Crossfire / SLI/2/3
PRO        WiFi / Bluetooth / 6 x USB-3 / Crossfire / SLI/2/3
PLUS                          6 x USB-3 / Crossfire / SLI/2            
A                             4 x USB-3 / Crossfire / SLI/2            
M-PLUS                        4 x USB-3 / Crossfire 
C                             4 x USB-3 / Crossfire 
K                             2 x USB-3 / Crossfire
```